# Neither Solve nor NSolve able to solve my trig equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I get a no result with this:

```
Solve[((2 a^2 Cos[t] - 2 a^2 b Cos[t] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + 
         a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 
         2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]) (-2 a^2 Sin[2 t] + 
       2 b^2 Sin[2 t]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - 
      b^2 Cos[2 t])^2 - (-2 a^2 Sin[t] + 
     2 a^2 b Sin[t] + (-2 a^2 b^2 Sin[2 t] - 2 a^4 b^2 Sin[2 t] + 
      4 a^2 b^3 Sin[2 t])/(
     Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + 
       a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]))/(
    a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t]) == 0 /. {a -> 0.9, 
   b -> 0.7}, t]

 {}
```

and

```
NSolve[-((0.64 (0.486 Cos[t] + 
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]]) Sin[2 t])/(1.3 + 
     0.32 Cos[2 t])^2) - (-0.486 Sin[t] - (0.230134 Sin[2 t])/Sqrt[
   0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]])/(1.3 + 0.32 Cos[2 t]) == 0,t]
{}
```

despite the expressions being smooth and continuous and having a solution near `t = .73`.

```
Plot[-((0.64 (0.486 Cos[t] + 
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]]) Sin[2 t])/(1.3 + 
     0.32 Cos[2 t])^2) - (-0.486 Sin[t] - (0.230134 Sin[2 t])/Sqrt[
   0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]])/(1.3 + 0.32 Cos[2 t]),{t,0,Pi/2}]
```

I was trying to get a general solution to:

```
Solve[((2 a^2 Cos[t] - 2 a^2 b Cos[t] + 
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] +
         a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]) (-2 a^2 Sin[2 t] + 
      2 b^2 Sin[2 t]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - 
     b^2 Cos[2 t])^2 - (-2 a^2 Sin[t] + 
    2 a^2 b Sin[t] + (-2 a^2 b^2 Sin[2 t] - 2 a^4 b^2 Sin[2 t] + 
     4 a^2 b^3 Sin[2 t])/(
    Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + 
      a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]))/(
   a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t]) == 0, t]
```

Any ideas? 
What is likelihood Mathematica can solve and will cloud version perform better?

Answer (score 4):

This is yet another case where the Weierstrass substitution helps a great deal:

```
eq = ((2 a^2 Cos[t] - 2 a^2 b Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 +
      a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]) (-2 a^2 Sin[2 t] + 
      2 b^2 Sin[2 t]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t])^2 - (-2 a^2 Sin[t] + 
      2 a^2 b Sin[t] + (-2 a^2 b^2 Sin[2 t] - 2 a^4 b^2 Sin[2 t] + 4 a^2 b^3 Sin[2 t])/
     (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] -
      2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t]);

2 ArcTan[u] /.
FullSimplify[Solve[((TrigExpand //@ eq) /.
                    Join[Thread[{Cos[t], Sin[t]} -> {1 - u^2, 2 u}/(1 + u^2)],
                         {a -> 9/10, b -> 7/10}]) == 0, u, Reals]]
(* 
   {0, 
    2 ArcTan[Root[583 - 4082 #1^2 + 583 #1^4 &, 2]], 
    2 ArcTan[Root[583 - 4082 #1^2 + 583 #1^4 &, 3]]}
*)

N[%]
(* {0., -0.729642, 0.729642} *)
```

It should be noted that the Weierstrass substitution, as designed, will miss the possibility that $t=\pi$ is a solution. Evaluating `eq /. t -> π` gives `0`, so this should be added to the list of solutions given above.

All the other real solutions can then be obtained by adding or subtracting multiples of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = -((0.64 (0.486 Cos[t] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]]) Sin[2 t])/(1.3 + 
          0.32 Cos[2 t])^2) - (-0.486 Sin[t] - (0.230134 Sin[2 t])/
        Sqrt[0.480249 + 0.162729 Cos[2 t]])/(1.3 + 0.32 Cos[2 t]) // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify

(* ((7479355 - 7683984 Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 t] + 
   15309 Sqrt[121 + 41 Cos[2 t]] (41 Sin[t] - 8 Sin[3 t]) + 
   8 (115067 - 162729 Sqrt[2]) Sin[4 t])/(630 (65 + 16 Cos[2 t])^2 Sqrt[
   121 + 41 Cos[2 t]]) *)

Plot[expr, {t, -3 π, 3 π}]
```

[image]

The expression has a period of 2 π

```
expr == (expr /. t -> t + 2 π) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

There are **four** roots in each period.

```
soln = Reduce[expr == 0, t, Reals]

(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && 
   t == π + 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] ∈ 
    Integers && (t == 2 π C[1] || 
     t == 2 ArcTan[
         Root[{-2 + #1^2 &, -8501720457913567281937233 + 
             33857471624559052054045950 #2^2 + 
             13104209414736904620022272 #1 #2^2 + 
             3039042896331738925940177 #2^4 + 
             14093502519541457307746304 #1 #2^4 + 
             73102258095784231497841412 #2^6 + 
             29815344580941773221874688 #1 #2^6 + 
             3039042896331738925940177 #2^8 + 
             14093502519541457307746304 #1 #2^8 + 
             33857471624559052054045950 #2^10 + 
             13104209414736904620022272 #1 #2^10 - 
             8501720457913567281937233 #2^12 &}, {2, 2}]] + 2 π C[1] || 
     t == 2 ArcTan[
         Root[{-2 + #1^2 &, -8501720457913567281937233 + 
             33857471624559052054045950 #2^2 + 
             13104209414736904620022272 #1 #2^2 + 
             3039042896331738925940177 #2^4 + 
             14093502519541457307746304 #1 #2^4 + 
             73102258095784231497841412 #2^6 + 
             29815344580941773221874688 #1 #2^6 + 
             3039042896331738925940177 #2^8 + 
             14093502519541457307746304 #1 #2^8 + 
             33857471624559052054045950 #2^10 + 
             13104209414736904620022272 #1 #2^10 - 
             8501720457913567281937233 #2^12 &}, {2, 3}]] + 2 π C[1])) *)
```

Their approximate numeric values are

```
soln // N

(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && 
   t == 3.14159 + 6.28319 C[1]) || (C[1] ∈ 
    Integers && (t == 6.28319 C[1] || t == -0.729641 + 6.28319 C[1] || 
     t == 0.729641 + 6.28319 C[1])) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function has an infinite number of solutions. `Solve` or `NSolve` cannot show them all. In such cases, you have to specify a particular region say `-1<t<1`.

```
Block[{a = 0.9, b = 0.7},
NSolve[((2 a^2 Cos[t] - 2 a^2 b Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + 
         a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]) (-2 a^2 Sin[2 t] + 
      2 b^2 Sin[2 t]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t])^2 - (-2 a^2 Sin[t] + 
    2 a^2 b Sin[t] + (-2 a^2 b^2 Sin[2 t] - 2 a^4 b^2 Sin[2 t] + 
       4 a^2 b^3 Sin[2 t])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a^2 b^2 + a^4 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + 
         a^2 b^2 Cos[2 t] + a^4 b^2 Cos[2 t] - 
     2 a^2 b^3 Cos[2 t]]))/(a^2 + b^2 + a^2 Cos[2 t] - b^2 Cos[2 t]) == 0

  && -1 < t < 1, t]]
```

> {{t -> -0.729642}, {t -> 0.}, {t -> 0.729642}}

If you want to find a root around a particular value, you can use `FindRoot`.

Comment: Thanks very much. So when {} is returned is this indicating multiple or infinite solutions or something else ?

Comment: @cumfy Note that `With[{a = 9/10, b = 7/10}, Solve[equation && t \[Element] Reals, t]]` gives you all real roots given `a` and `b`

Comment: `Solve` and `NSolve` are mostly for simple equations such as polynomials and they may not always work for equations like this one. Use `Reduce` to get a better result.

Comment: @cumfy, `{}` means either there is no solution, or it is not possible for mathematica under that circumstance. In such cases, you can `Plot` your function to see what might be the actual reason.